# Is "A New Kind of Science" a new kind of science?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

A couple of years ago I was reading "New Kind of Science" (NKS) by S. Wolfram, and it presented lot of interesting ideas for a young Physics undergraduate. Now that I am studying Mathematics however, I realise that many ideas of NKS seem to be not so novel afterall, and contained in the Maths literature already, yet with different names.

Is NKS actually presenting novel material?

If yes, what in particular?

If not, what authors have already done this kind of work? Is NKS a "repackaging" of ideas?

Comment: A new kind of self-aggrandisement.

Comment: Wolfram has a reputation as a bit of an egomaniac.  So I'd take it with a grain of salt.   Here are some quotes he wrote about himself.

"Stephen Wolfram is the creator of Mathematica and is widely regarded as the most important innovator in scientific and technical computing today."

and "Stephen Wolfram is the creator of Mathematica, and a well-known scientist. He is widely regarded as the most important innovator in technical computing today, as well as one of the world's most original research scientists."

That's just not the kind of thing you say about yourself.

Comment: May be relevant: http://www.ams.org/notices/200302/fea-gray.pdf

Comment: This may be flagged as offensive...but I've always thought of Stephen Wolfram as a bit of a douche. See Gregory's comments for more details and the litany of egotestical remarks made by Wolfram. He's why we can't have nice things...and why Wolfram|Alpha pro sucks.

Comment: Mr. Stephen Wolfram certainly isn't “the most important innovator in scientific and technical computing today” or “the world's most original research scientists”... *I am* ! :-|

Comment: "I suppose another feature of the book that did not endear it to some academics was the very intensity of positive reaction that accompanied its release" - http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2012/05/living-a-paradigm-shift-looking-back-on-reactions-to-a-new-kind-of-science/

Comment: He also shows s a pie-chart showing the breakdown of #-star reviews NKS received.  I think I understand @Magic's remark.

Comment: He could atleast make wolframalpha free for students.

Comment: While your distress may be justified, this question is not about S. Wolfram's personality or business model. In fact, these comments are not helpful if one is aiming at weighing the validity of certain ideas.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, that review is the most helpful I have read. Thank you very much.

Comment: There are good popular expositions of Wolfram's definite contributions to mathematics in the book. But not only is this field not as novel in Mathematics as Wolfram makes out (as you observe), there are definite problems with its physics. In particular, it would seems to be in conflict with Bell's theorem unless the cellular automata were grossly nonlocal - so not realizable in any technology for the foreseeable future and certainly quite at odds from a literal reading of how Wolfram sees this stuff computed. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4200/26076

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After reading the reviews that were linked in the comments [1] and @Mark's helpful answer[2][3], I came to a a few conclusions, that answer my questions.

First, let's get something out of the way. Stephen Wolfram is definitely a polariser of opinion. Plus his way of presenting himself and his work are not in the canons of the scientific literature and that is bound to make people upset. Plus, the habit of not mentioning other people's contributions and the legal actions make it more so. But the question is *not* about Wolfram, the question is about the book and the ideas.

## Novel Ideas

It seems to me that the most novel aspect of NKS is the proposed "paradigm shift". Namely, that to proceed in Mathematics and Physics we should abandon constructing more complicated and sophisticated theories. Instead, we should focus our attention to simple programs, such as the Cellular Automata (CA), and instead of trying to *prove* properties of these, we can learn about them by looking at outputs of simulations.

The validity of this paradigm remains to be proven because, according to the 3 reviews I have read, no real predictions have been made.

Another novel part of the book seems to be the "Principle of Computational Equivalence". It basically means according  to [1] that there are two classes of computations: the simple/easily predictable ones, and all the "computationally irreducible", equivalent to each other. This implies that all CA complex enough, or rather, complex *looking* enough, are Turing equivalent. This principle, apart from not being well defined in the book, also seems to be false, according to the reviewers.

## Work has already been done

Turns out a lot of work had been done on CA at the time of publishing. This has been done with the "Old Kind of Science", i.e. with proofs and all. In particular Conway's work on the Game of Life, and the fact of it being Turing equivalent. NKS does contain a lot of info and discussion about 2D CA and other programs, with links to the real world. Some of this is original, some is not.

Then there is the work of mathematicians in complexity theory that can be said to touch the same concepts as NKS.

In the end, NKS does appear to be a repackaging of ideas, in order to call to a new paradigm of doing science. If this will work, remains to be proven.

### Sources

[1] A very useful, balanced and justified review. Recommended.
http://www.ams.org/notices/200302/fea-gray.pdf

[2] Negative review. The arguments about the content are convincing.
http://bactra.org/reviews/wolfram/

[3] Positive review. Not as balanced in my opinion. I was not convinced by it.
http://sjsu.rudyrucker.com/~rudy.rucker/wolfram_review_AMM_11_2003.pdf

Comment: A reasonable assessment! I would point out, though, that the many of the ideas that he "repackaged" are, in fact, his own. From a personal perspective, I've found his numbering schemes of CAs to be quite useful and his paper [Geometry of Binomail Coefficients](http://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/academic/geometry-binomial-coefficients.pdf) to be delightful.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I don't think anyone would complain about Wolfram repackaging his own ideas: that is inevitable if one is to write a book popularizing those ideas. The problems come when other people's ideas are repackaged. Most of the reviews I've read agree that Wolfram did some great research on CAs in the '80s.

Answer (score 62):

I think the answer to this question is, unfortunately, a little difficult. As many will point out, Wolfram is beyond egotistical and that fact definitely colors the reception of the book.  There is a long list of (mostly negative) reviews [here](http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~wclark/ANKOS_reviews.html).  The negativity reaches its apex in the [review by Cosma Shalizi](http://bactra.org/reviews/wolfram/). There are some positive reviews as well, though, such as the [one by Rudy Rucker](http://sjsu.rudyrucker.com/~rudy.rucker/wolfram_review_AMM_11_2003.pdf).

So, what is NKS?  Most correctly, I would say that it is a broad and semi-popular account of Wolfram's work in cellular automata.  For those in the field, it clearly builds on the work of others.  There are references to this fact in the text but it could certainly be made more explicit.  To more clearly see Wolfram's own contributions, you might examine his earlier collection of papers [Cellular Automata and Complexity](http://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/cellular-automata-complexity/).  Rucker lists several of these in his review as well.  An honest assessment of his earlier contributions reveal that he is certainly an important researcher in the field and most researchers would be happy to have his body of work.  Given the clear antecedents, however, I think that "New Kind of Science" is a definite overstatement.  He is in no danger of winning an Abel or Nobel prize.

So, the truth of NKS is certainly somewhere in the huge gulf between a revolutionary (well) new kind of science and (as Shalizi puts it) "utter bat shit insanity".

Comment: Shalizi's review might be one of the most fun literature reviews I've ever read.

Comment: Mike Miller I read the review based on your comment.  Rick and Morty is funny, that review however is not.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Very useful.

Comment: @MikeMiller I actually like the review just because I think it's hysterical, in the same way that [harsh reviews](http://www.thebestpageintheuniverse.net/c.cgi?u=irule) can be funny.  I don't particularly agree with it, though.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I opened your profile, and was surprised to learn that you worked part-time for Wolfram Research. Did you have any encounters with S. Wolfram?

Comment: @Newb Of course. But then, a major point that I'm trying to get across in my answer is that, ideally, evaluation of the person should not affect evaluation of his work. As such, this seems to be the wrong place to expand on those experiences.

Comment: Although your answer comes across as balanced, I do think you should state explicitly in it that you're not entirely disinterested.

Comment: @DavidRicherby If I wasn't interested, I wouldn't have answered. :)  Perhaps, you're implying that I have a conflict of interest?  As I am not currently employed at Wolfram Research, I don't believe that I do.  I make heavy use of Mathematica in my work but that's hardly a secret and, again, I think that is very separate from my evaluation of NKS.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Disinterested $\neq$ uninterested.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: [Are you sure about that](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Disinterested)? (See especially the usage notes.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes, I'm sure about that. Disinterested = {unbiased, bored} $\neq$ {bored} = uninterested. And, as the usage note says, "the sense intended is almost always clear from the context". It's clear that I'm talking about potential bias, rather than boredom.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you for your clarification. I assure you, I am disinterested by your definition. Have a look at [my answer](http://goo.gl/pAz76M) to [this question](http://goo.gl/J94HK5); does it look like the answer of someone pushing a Wolfram agenda to you? Also, when you say my answer "comes across" as balanced, I guess you're implying that it's not. I wonder, would you expect my direct experience with Wolfram to skew me in the direction of a favorable opinion of NKS? Or an unfavorable one? Could be either, I suppose.

Comment: @MarkMcClure No, it doesn't look like you're pushing either a pro- or anti-Wolfram agenda. All I'm saying is that being a former employee of the author of the book could have slightly altered your perceptions and that I think you should, therefore, mention that fact as a footnote to your answer. Since you disclose that information in your profile anyway, I don't really understand your resistance.

Comment: @DavidRicherby My resistance is threefold. First and again, a major point behind my answer is that evaluation of NKS (the book) can and should be done independently of the author and I believe I've done so. Second, I think I've already far exceeded the standards of this site, which allows anonymous users. Finally (and to be quite honest), after my experience with you [here](http://goo.gl/SS3PLH), it seems to me that you are the one who is biased. I never did understand your objection to that answer, which seems quite fine to me.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Um. You're saying that the book should be reviewed independently of its author but one of your reasons for rejecting my request is that it was made by me, rather than by somebody else.  Fiiiiiine.

Comment: I see no reason to remove a *quote* that uses somewhat colorful language (while not being excessive), especially in this case as the author of the post does *not* even embrace the quote, but instead presents it as an extreme view that in his opinion does not describe the work adequately. (At least this is my understanding of the post.)

Comment: @quid Yes, I think you articulated it accurately - thanks!

Comment: @FamousMichaelWang At this point, either you or another "Michael Wang" has edited this post four times to "remove an expletive". Please stop doing so. The expletive is part of a quote that, I believe strengthens the post. Please note also that I flagged this post for moderator attention a week ago resulting in the comment by the moderator quid on June 1. Thanks.

Comment: Oh. Now I understand.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that asking if something is novel in science is actually very tricky because almost every scientific idea is based on previous work. Therefore, I don't think it is very valuable to question whether something is novel or not because it most certainly is not. However, you can ask if a particular work offers something interesting or particularly noteworthy. I will enumerate a few prominent ideas explained in NKS, including previous work (which is more or less what you asked):

1. A proposed method to analyse complex systems is to explore the computational universe to see what simple programs are able to do and document their behavior using experimental or analytic methods. Previous work: Edward Fredkin and Konrad Zuse proposed the idea that the universe might be a cellular automaton. In 1997, Schmidhuber described a Turing machine capable of computing all possible histories for the universe based on physical laws.
2. Principle of computational irreducibility. Systems that display complex behavior can not be reduced and we need to run the experiment to see the outcome.
3. Principle of computational equivalence. Most sufficiently complex systems are computationally equivalent.
4. Turing completeness of Rule 110. Wolfram conjectured this in 1985. Matthew Cook (who worked as a research assistant to Wolfram) published a proof in 2000 and a legal battle ensued due to a violation of an NDA. Previous work: Conway's Game of Life, Von Neumann's idea of self-replicating machines.
5. Conjecture that the 2-state 3-symbol Turing machine is universal. Alex Smith proved this conjecture in 2007.

There are other interesting ideas but most of them are extremely speculative and unlikely to be confirmed or falsified by evidence any time soon.

Comment: Thanks for the useful reply. The Reviews I have read say that 2. and 3. in your reply are actually false. They don't present a proof in the review though. Do you know of anybody that proved that?

Comment: Try not to put much weight on reviews (positive or negative reviews). In this case, reviews are not really appropriate because they are more journalistic in nature than scientific. As far as I know, 2 and 3 have not been proven wrong. They are incompatible with other theories or observations to the same extent that pretty much any theory is incompatible with something else. Instead, we should ask "Does the theory predict something specific?" If so, then we should be able to falsify such predictions.

Comment: A concrete question: NKS claims that CA rule 30 is computational irreducible, and the principle of computational equivalence would then imply that rule 30 is also Turing equivalent. (This of course assuming that being computationally irreducible means satisfying the "complex enough" criterion) .This could be falsified or confirmed by proof. Has this been done?

Comment: NKS claims CA rule might be computational irreducible but there is no proof of this, in no small part due to the lack of a well-defined notion of what computational irreducibility actually means. There is also no proof that rule 30 is Turing complete (unlike rule 110). If it is truly a property of every "complex" system in the universe, then it would be pointless to try to define it precisely, in the same way that we can't really define inertia and instead, we generally accept it as a property of our universe.

Comment: @RobertSmith Actually, most of the reviews linked from this page *are* scientific (in particular, [Lawrence Gray's review](http://www.ams.org/notices/200302/fea-gray.pdf) in the *Notices of the AMS* and the [review by Cosma Shalizi](http://bactra.org/reviews/wolfram/), who's worked on CAs). This kind of review is such an important part of the scientific process that it's a mandatory part of getting a paper published in a reputable journal. And all the scientific reviews of ANKS that I've read (admittedly, just a handful) have found scientific flaws with the book.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm not sure. The reviews you describe are very superficial  and in the case of Gray's review, it tries to compress a 1200+ page book into a 12 page review. it is certainly informative but definitely not scientific.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I think that you are missing that  "review" is used in two very different senses. You have "reviewing" in the sense of refereeing a book or a paper for a journal, and "reviewing" in the sense of commenting an article or book. The reviews mentioned above belong to the second category, and as such they are nowhere as "scientific" as those of the first kind.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I don't think I'm missing it at all. Although they are book-review reviews, they analyze the scientific claims in detail and find scientific errors. They would, therefore, serve just fine as peer-review reviews with a conclusion of either "reject" or "major revision needed".