# For $n>2, n\in\mathbb{Z}$, why is this true: $\left\lfloor 1/\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n+n)^2}\right)\right\rfloor=2n-3$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $n>2$ be a positive integer, prove that
$$\left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{(n+n)^2}}\right\rfloor=2n-3?$$

before I use hand Calculation $n=2,3,4$,maybe I calculation some wrong,I can't use computer it!

so maybe this result  is right. But how to  prove the statement?

Comment: The upvotes though.

Comment: It doesn't appear accurate, [See wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor%281%2F%28sum+from+i%3D0+to+n+1%2F%28n%2Bi%29^2%29%29) it appears to give the sequence 0,2,4,6,7,9,11 which is certainly not linear in $n$

Comment: Suddenly all the upvotes are gone...

Comment: @wythagoras I guess people thought that this question isn't upvote worthy once Wolfram showed identity false :P

Comment: A more interesting question would be: Can it shown to be 2n-3+o(1)?

Comment: You can write this as $\frac{n}{\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{r}{n})^2}}$  I wish, this were a integral. I wonder if it shows anything.

Comment: @JMoravitz,I think is true $n>2?$

Comment: What is interesting is that, without the floor function, the asymptotic development of the lhs would be $2 n-\frac{5}{2}+\frac{61}{24 n}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right)$ (this is related to polylogarithms).

Comment: @Australia as evidenced by my earlier comment, the statement does not hold for $n=1..4$.  It begins to match at $n=5$.  For $n=4$ it becomes [$\approx 6.01$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281%2F4^2+%2B+1%2F5^2%2B1%2F6^2%2B1%2F7^2%2B1%2F8^2%29) before applying the floor function.  You say you checked the identity for $n=1..6$, now you say $n=3..6$.  Have you actually checked any of the cases at all?

Comment: maybe is Calculation wrong by hand,I don't use computer calculation it

Comment: @Wojowu Actually, I think the *downvotes* are from people who are familiar with OP and the kind of questions often asked--hard questions with little to no context. Some of those questions are fine, but it gets to be annoying/tiresome after a while.

Comment: @MagicMan What I said was intended to be a joke (if you didn't realize) but I can understand what you mean - I can see why this can tend to be tiresome.

Comment: @Wojowu I was responding more to the "upvote" portion of your comment than the Wolfram remark...Wolfram...[what a douche](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228625/is-a-new-kind-of-science-a-new-kind-of-science) (check out the comments haha).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(n) = \dfrac1{n^2} + \dfrac1{(n+1)^2} + \cdots + \dfrac1{(2n)^2}$.
We then have
$$\int_{n-1}^{2n} \dfrac{dx}{x^2} > \dfrac1{n^2} + \dfrac1{(n+1)^2} + \cdots + \dfrac1{(2n)^2} \geq \int_n^{2n+1} \dfrac{dx}{x^2}$$
This gives us
$$\dfrac1n-\dfrac1{2n+1}  < f(n) < \dfrac1{n-1} - \dfrac1{2n} \implies \dfrac{n+1}{n(2n+1)} < f(n) < \dfrac{n+1}{2n(n-1)}$$
Hence, we have
$$\dfrac{2n^2-2n}{n+1}< \dfrac1{f(n)} < \dfrac{2n^2+n}{n+1} \implies 2n - \dfrac{4n}{n+1} < \dfrac1{f(n)} < 2n - \dfrac{n}{n+1}$$
A tighter bound using this integral approach ([ala Euler–Maclaurin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)) should provide the answer.

---

**EDIT** For a more precise answer, we have
\begin{align}
f(n) & = \int_{n^-}^{2n^+} \dfrac{d\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^2} = \left.\dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^2} \right \vert_{n^-}^{2n^+} + \int_{n^-}^{2n^+} \dfrac{2\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^3}dx =\dfrac1{2n} - \dfrac{n-1}{n^2} + \int_{n^-}^{2n^+}\dfrac{2x-2\{x\}}{x^3}dx\\
& = \dfrac{n-2n+2}{2n^2} + \dfrac1n - 2\int_{n^-}^{2n^+} \dfrac{\{x\}}{x^3}dx = \dfrac{n+2}{2n^2} - 2\int_{n^-}^{2n^+} \dfrac{\{x\}-1/2}{x^3}dx  -\int_{n^-}^{2n^+} \dfrac{dx}{x^3}\\
& = \dfrac{n+2}{2n^2} - 2\int_{n^-}^{2n^+} \dfrac{\{x\}-1/2}{x^3}dx  -\dfrac3{8n^2} = \dfrac1{2n} + \dfrac5{8n^2} + \mathcal{O}(1/n^3) = \dfrac1{2n}\left(1+\dfrac5{4n} + \mathcal{O}(1/n^2)\right)
\end{align}
This means
$$\dfrac1{f(n)} = \dfrac{2n}{1+\dfrac5{4n} + \mathcal{O}(1/n^2)} = 2n\left(1-\dfrac5{4n} + \mathcal{O}(1/n^2)\right) = 2n-\dfrac52 + \mathcal{O}(1/n)$$
Hence, we have
$$\left\lfloor \dfrac1{f(n)} \right\rfloor = 2n-3$$ eventually (in fact for $n > 4$).

Comment: in your result, may be is $2n-3,2n-2,2n-1$ But How to sure is $2n-3$?

Comment: @Australia Thats why I have mentioned "A tighter bound using this integral approach ([ala Euler–Maclaurin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)) should provide the answer."

Answer (score 2):

Asymptotically,
$$ \sum_{i=n}^{2n} \dfrac{1}{i^2} = \dfrac{1}{2n} + \dfrac{5}{8n^2} + O(1/n^3)$$
so
$$ \dfrac{1}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=n}^{2n} \dfrac{1}{i^2}} = 2n - \dfrac{5}{2} + O(1/n) $$

Thus your equation will be true for sufficiently large $n$.  With sufficiently good explicit bounds on the $O(1/n^3)$ term, you should be able to prove that it is true for all $n \ge 5$.

EDIT: For an explicit upper bound, since $1/x^2$ is convex, 
$$\dfrac{1}{i^2} \le \int_{i-1/2}^{i+1/2} \dfrac{dt}{t^2}$$
so
$$ \sum_{i=n}^{2n} \dfrac{1}{i^2} \le \int_{n-1/2}^{2n+1/2} \dfrac{dt}{t^2} = 
\dfrac{4(n+1)}{(2n-1)(4n+1)} $$
Call this upper bound $U(n)$.  We have
$$ \dfrac{1}{\sum_{i=n}^{2n} \dfrac{1}{i^2} } \ge \dfrac{1}{U(n)}  = 2 n - \dfrac{5}{2} + \dfrac{9}{4(n+1)} > 2 n - \dfrac{5}{2}$$

For a lower bound,  consider
$$ g(i) = \int_{i-1/2}^{i+1/2} \left( \dfrac{1}{t^2} - \dfrac{1}{4t^4}\right)\; dt
= \dfrac{4 (4 i^2 - 16 i - 1)}{(4 i^2 - 1)^2} $$
Now 
$$ \dfrac{1}{i^2} - g(i) = \dfrac{64 i^3 - 4 i^2 + 1}{(4 i^2-1)^2 i^2} > 0$$
for $i \ge 1$.  Thus
$$ \sum_{i=n}^{2n} \dfrac{1}{i^2} \ge \int_{n-1/2}^{2n+1/2} \left(\dfrac{1}{t^2} - \dfrac{1}{4t^4}\right)\; dt = {\frac {8 \left( n+1 \right)  \left( 96\,{n}^{4}-48\,{n}^{3}-32\,{
n}^{2}+5\,n+1 \right) }{3 \left( 2\,n - 1 \right) ^{3} \left( 4\,n+1
 \right) ^{3}}}
$$
which I will call $L(n)$.  Now 
$$\dfrac{1}{L(n)} - (2n - 2) =  -{\frac {384\,{n}^{5}-1760\,{n}^{4}+584\,{n}^{3}+492\,{n}^{2}-62
\,n-13}{ 8 \left( n+1 \right)  \left( 96\,{n}^{4}-48\,{n}^{3}-32\,{n}^{2
}+5\,n+1 \right) }}
$$
which is negative for $n \ge 5$ (you can verify using Sturm's theorem that the numerator and denominator have no zeros for $n \ge 5$).
Thus $$\dfrac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=n}^{2n} \dfrac{1}{i^2}} < 2n-2 \ \text{for}\ n \ge 5$$

Comment: why $\sum_{i=n}^{2n}\dfrac{1}{i^2}=\dfrac{1}{2n}+\dfrac{5}{8n^2}+o()$

Comment: Euler-Maclaurin series.

Comment: @Australia See my answer for complete details.